# How to create vertical continuous legend without rotating the legend

Tags: d3.js, legend, linear-gradients, continuous

I have created the horizontal continous legend using linear gradient. But my legend can be either horizonatl or vertical based on the flag. How can i make same legend vertical but i do not want to rotate it as it takes too much space.

```
const svgLegend = select(divRef.current).append("svg")
const defs = svgLegend.append("defs")
const linearGradient = defs
.append("linearGradient")
.attr("id", "linear-gradient")
.attr("x1", "0%")
.attr("x2", "100%") //since it's a horizontal linear gradient
.attr("y2", "0%");
```

// other code to add color

```
svgLegend
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 25)
.attr("y", 30)
.attr("width", 250)
.attr("height", 25)
.style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient)");

const xLeg = scaleLinear().domain([min, max]).range([10, 258]);
const axisLeg = axisBottom(xLeg).tickValues(colorScale.domain());
svgLegend
.attr("class", "axis")
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(15, 55)")
.style("font-size", "10px")
.style("font-weight", "700")
.call(axisLeg);
```

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/r1t60ges/3/

Desired Output : [image]

Comment: can you add an image of your desired output?

Comment: @Mouri I have updated my question with desired output

Comment: why are you not trying to draw it in the y-axis? if you can draw it on the x-axis you can also draw it on the y-axis right??

Comment: Can you share me the short code snippet like how can I draw it in x-axis ? I am pretty new to this concept.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fg8prsd4/

Comment: Thanks your solution works. Just had one query like can we give any height and width for both svg and rect or it should be given based on some calculations ? I mean the final aim is to show all the colors in the legend.

Comment: You can use any height,width...but svg height,width should always be greater than rect

Comment: @Mouri how can i reverse the direction of the color? As in this https://jsfiddle.net/fg8prsd4/ i want red to be at bottom and blue at the top without rotating it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ay937Le/1/ is it ok? @coder91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg class="axis" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); border-radius: 5px;">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"></stop>
            <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ffff00"></stop><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#00ff00"></stop>
            <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#00ffff"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000ff"></stop>
        </linearGradient></defs>
        <text class="legendTitle" x="25" y="10">Legend</text>
        <rect x="25" y="20" width="25" height="150" style="fill: url(&quot;#linear-gradient&quot;);"></rect>
          <g transform="translate(15, 55)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 700;">
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: If you could edit your code, may be then I can accept this answer and upvote because now the legend shows full black in color . Your earlier jsfiddle link works anyhow.

Comment: As you see in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r1t60ges/3/ I have axis too (min and max). How can I make them too vertical along with the legend ?

Comment: I could make them vertical by using axisRight and it works but issue is the axis is taking more height than the legend. How can I make axis also take the same height as of the legend.

Comment: Please add code snippet,it will be easy for me to solve

Comment: Now I have somehow adjust the axis by giving default value but I an sure if it is the correct way I am doing. const yLeg = scaleLinear().domain([min, max]).range([10, 127]);
var VerticalAxisLeg = axisRight(yLeg).tickSize(24).tickValues(colorScale.domain());
svgLegend
.attr("class", "axis")
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(25, 20)")
.call(VerticalAxisLeg);